# Multiple JPanel Visibility

Tags: layout, formatting, jpanel, visibility

Sorry to bother with simple questions but as I learn JAVA I am having a few issues and the first one of those is with programing a GUI.  I am first forming a JFrame and then placing JPanels within it.  basically with the code below looking to make two boxes that outline JPanels, one on the top and one along the left side of the jframe.  These will later be used as containers for other elements but just trying to get the outlines to show first.  I did a bit of research and added a repaint line for the second panel but not the answer code below, any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class frmTest {
    public static void main(String main[]){
        JFrame test = new JFrame();
        test.setSize(1300,800);
        test.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setSize(1300,100);
        panel1.setLocation(0, 0);
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setSize(200,700);
        panel2.setLocation(0,100);
        panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        test.add(panel1);
        test.add(panel2);
        panel1.setVisible(true);
        panel2.setVisible(true);
        panel2.repaint();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use BorderLayout. [Here's the tutorial.](http://bit.ly/11q617c). Good luck with learning swing.

Comment: Not just swing....my learning expands to all of JAVA been working at it hard this week but slow going thanks for the tutorial....I had thought it was an issue with the way I had the JPanels set up

Comment: I'll have to try again tmw but initially this tutorial deals with location....applying the borderlayout(West) to panel2 make both disappear.  Still not able to see each panel....follow up tmw could be sleepy